# How do you get value of segmented control on flipside view for mainview Calculation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

How do you get value of segmented control on flipside view for mainview Calculation?

Comment: Does the main view create the flipside view?  Where and is the flipside view an ivar in the mainview.h?

Comment: Its the utility template app in SDK. I haven't made a variable yet, just trying to figure out how to get the value and give it a variable. Hope I understood your question correctly?

Comment: This doesnt seem like a popular question, I haven't been able to find how to do this anywhere. Just have a utility template from the SDK, and trying to get the value of my segment controller from the flipside view. Seems simple enough, but have yet to find out how.can somebody please take a few minutes to help me out. I would greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: Got this to work by adding a label in my view that I'm trying to send it too...so in the mainview.m i added `- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller {
    
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    
    //Gets the title of segmented control.
    RiseSegPrefLabel.text =[controller.RiseSegmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:controller.RiseSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
    
    TredWidthField.text = [controller.TredSegmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:controller.TredSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
    
}`
Now just grab the value

Comment: Cont... from the label and it works. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529469/iphone-utility-application-connection-from-flipsideview-to-mainview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a variable in your Controller (not your view, link your actions from your view to the controller in Interface Builder).
Then you can do two things:

a) When this:

```
-(IBAction)CalculateButton:(id)sender
```

is triggered. Let the controller get the values from the flip side view and do the calculation.

b) Make a Model object (maybe very advanced for the size of the app, but its a good design and a best practice)

```
@interface CalculateObject : NSObject {
   //Some variables
}
//@property for all variables

- (...) doCalculation;
@end
```

When the segment controls change and the controller receives the action, call the correct setter in your model. Then when the calculate button is called. Just call the doCalculate method.

Note: I'm not sure if you know about the Model-View-Controller pattern, but if you don't see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–View–Controller

Comment: Sorry, everything is in the controllers, updated the .h and .m files to reflect this, does this change the code any? Also, I have been trying to declare the segmented controller as a variable, but keep getting making a pointer without a cast error.

Comment: Actually the code should not change, only the responsibilities change. The controller owns all/the view(s). It can read the values of its view. Pointer without a cast means you assign a value of a different type, can be a integer to NSNumber or NSString. Check the variable types in you assignment.

Comment: So this method would go in the Flipsideview controller or Mainview controller?

Comment: Not really understanding how this answered my original question?

Comment: Sorry. My miss understanding. You have two controllers.1, when the segment changes save a value in your flipside controller(the result of your valueChanged method), then acces its value from the MainViewController through FlipSideViewController.theValue, then make your calculation. 2. Make a model as i described before. Share this object between both controllers and implement a calculate method. Set a ModelObject-property in FlipSideViewController from the MainController so they can both access it. Then when the calculateButton action is called get the values from the model.

Comment: actually I'm saving using NSUserDefaults, Not the valuechanged action. Right now I don't think the valuechanged does anything, I made that thinking that's what I could call it on the mainview.

Comment: I have tried what Mats suggested, and have yet to find a way to get it to work. If anyone understands what Mats is saying, could you please give some more details? I'm afraid it's a vague answer for for a beginner, and I have yet to find anyone that has a solid answer for this question. I have googled it, read many books and looked at the apple dev site, and I have yet to find how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Please look at code again for -(IBAction)CalculateButton. If you also want to know how this is done, please hit the vote at the top left!