# iPhone utility application, connection from FLipSideView to MainView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, view

I'm trying to learn Objective-C and iPhone programming, but I'm stuck with a problem. I have a utility application, and I have a text on my MainView and a button that change the text when I click it. Easy, and workes great. But what if I wan't to place the button on the "backside" in the FlipSideView, and still make it change the text on the frontside (MainView)? How do I get the views to talk together? I have tried a lot of different things, and searched for an answear, but can't seem to figure it out.

Would be great if someone had a answear, or maybe a link to a tutorial/example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you've used the template which implements the following method in the `MainViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {    

    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
...
}
```

As you can see it sets the delegate of the FlipSideController to the instance of the MainViewController.

A way would be to put an action into your `FlipSideViewController`, something like this:

```
- (IBAction)changeTextInMainView
{
    [(MainViewController *)self.delegate changeText];
}
```

which is triggered when touching your button on the backside. You've got to wire it in IB as well as add the method to the header.

Then implement something like this in your `MainViewController`

```
- (void)changeText
{
    self.myLabel.text = @"text changed to this";
}
```

Add this method to the header as well.

Another more elegant approach would be to save the text of your label in a property(maybe in it's own model class) which can be accessed from any view, by passing it by reference down the controllers. Then add a Key Value Observer from each viewController to the property which should show the text and update the view.

Comment: Thnx for the answer, but it says "use of undeclared identifier (MainViewController *)". I have set it up, just like you described.

Comment: Put `#import "MainViewController.h"` directly after `#import "FlipsideViewController.h"` in a new line in your FlipsideViewController.m file.